# count clause to output all records in database - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I been trying different combination, but I cant seems to get this to work. I have inner join tables, I want to count the number of QA ISSUE found in the records and also output those records with only QA ISSUE, How would I do that?

```
SELECT d.department, m.mo_number, m.part_number, c.category,
COUNT(CASE WHEN c.category = 'QA ISSUE' THEN category END) as qa_issue,
SUM(CASE WHEN c.category = 'QA ISSUE' THEN time_spent END) as time_spent
FROM       master as m
INNER JOIN category as c ON c.cat_id = m.cat_id
INNER JOIN department as d ON d.dept_id = m.dept_id
WHERE m.date_created >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND
d.department = 'Electronics'
GROUP BY m.mo_number
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Can you pls provide some sample source data, expected output, and the output you get when you run your query?

Comment: why don't you put `c.category = 'QA ISSUE'` in `WHERE` instead of `COUNT` and `SUM`?

Comment: I want to count of all QA ISSUE records found and also sum of all values of QA ISSUE as time_spent for each department.

Comment: What is wrong with the query provided? It might be clear to you, because you can see the result it produces -  but all we see are a few words and some sql code - no data is available to use, and there is no "expected result" either. Please learn how to ask an effective questions - then you will get many more useful responses. Tips on how to ask a question: basics: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and for more info:  http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ (take particular note of "**Sample Code and Data**")

Answer (score 0):

To filter results by aggregates you use the HAVING clause which occurs after the GROUP BY clause. Note this is not a substitute for the WHERE clause (which chooses the rows to be aggregated).

```
SELECT
      d.department
    , m.mo_number
    , m.part_number
    , c.category
    , COUNT(*) AS qa_issue
    , SUM(time_spent) AS time_spent
FROM master AS m
      INNER JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = m.cat_id
      INNER JOIN department AS d ON d.dept_id = m.dept_id
WHERE m.date_created >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 50 DAY)
      AND d.department = 'Electronics'
      AND c.category = 'QA ISSUE'
GROUP BY
      d.department
    , m.mo_number
    , m.part_number
    , c.category

HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

ORDER BY
      d.department
```

I have also added a condition to the where clause and added all non-aggregated columns into the GROUP BY clause - which I recommend you do always.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My apology if I wasn't clear with my question. Your query works to a degree, that it fetches 2 records, but the sum should be sum of record 1 +  record 2 (sum(time_spent) = record1 + record2 which has value in time_spent column. at the moment result set is just a list not sum of the 2 values. Count should give me value 2 at the moment I am just getting list of 2 records. That what I was initially was getting. I dont know how to work this out.

Comment: Do it with DATA. Please do not attempt to describe the need in words. Use an **example** and add it to your question so it is easy to read. Read the urls I provided earlier, you will get a solution faster if your question is well prepared.